# Can I hardcode a column value when using Postgres' COPY FROM command?

Tags: postgresql

When performing some statement like:

`COPY table_name(col1, col2) FROM filename;`

Is it possible to specify a hard-coded value for col1, while shoveling each row into col2? The value for col1 can't be found inside of the file, but is available to the plsql that runs the statement.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. You need to provide more information 1) Example input data. 2) The exact process(commands) you are using. 3) Expected output. **ADD this information as text update to your question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's ok. I'd like for every col1 to be a particular value, while loading the rest from the file itself. I don't know how more simply this can be stated. I could go the other way and have 10 pages of extraneous detail, then I get complaints of "please remove as much detail as possible while still asking the question". If you need input, col1 should be 'whatever'::TEXT and the file contents should be random newline-delimited rows of a single column. Does the COPY FROM allow this? Does PGPLSQL allow this somehow? The data does not matter at all, I need the syntax for the command.

Comment: 1) I asked for the information to be added to the question. 2) Your existing question say` *Is it possible to specify a hard-coded value for col2, while shoveling each row into col2?`* which does not match what you say now.

Comment: Read it again , *..hard-coded value for col2, while shoveling each row into col2?*.  Whereas your comment says the hard coded value is in `col1`. Don't blame others for your lack of attention to detail. Given that [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) can pull from a `PROGRAM` the possibility exists that you can do that. I leave that to you to figure out since you obviously exist on a higher plane then the rest of us.

Answer (score 4):

Not in the `COPY` command itself, no. But in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) we find

> For `COPY FROM`, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column. Table columns not specified in the `COPY FROM` column list will receive their default values.

So if your file only contains the values of `col2`, you can do

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col1 SET DEFAULT '…';
COPY table_name(col2) FROM filename;
```

If that doesn't fit your case, you can either pipe the file through some script to put the hardcoded values in the stream that postgres reads from, or you can use a temporary table and manipulate that to your liking.